# How to slides the uploaded images using CodeIgniter

Tags: php, image, codeigniter, upload

In my application we can create shops. At that time we have to upload many images. Then we go to the detailed view of that particular shop, shows all images we uploaded in sliding manner that is display one another.

But I don't know how to create a for loop in view page.

**controller**

```
            for($i=0; $i<$cpt; $i++)
            {

                $_FILES['userfile']['name']= $files['userfile']['name'][$i];
                $_FILES['userfile']['type']= $files['userfile']['type'][$i];
                $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']= $files['userfile']['tmp_name'][$i];
                $_FILES['userfile']['error']= $files['userfile']['error'][$i];
                $_FILES['userfile']['size']= $files['userfile']['size'][$i];    

                $this->upload->initialize($this->set_upload_options($shop_id,$i));

                $this->upload->do_upload('userfile'); 
            }

            if (!$this->upload->do_upload('userfile'))
            {     
                echo $this->upload->display_errors();  
            }

            if($session_user_id != ''){
               $data['files'] = $files_uploaded;
               $this->load->view('header', $data);
               $this->load->view('shop_detail_view', $data);
               $this->load->view('footer',$data);
               // redirect(base_url().'user');
            }else{
                redirect(base_url().'login/index/shop/'.$shop_id);
            }


        private function set_upload_options($shop_id,$i)
        {   
           $config = array(); 
           $config['file_name']    = $shop_id.'_'.$i.'.jpg';   
           $config['upload_path'] = './application/assets/images/shops/';
           $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg';   
           return $config;
        }
```

Suppose upload 3 images that names are 2_0.jpg,2_1.jpg,2_2.jpg like that
2 is the shop_id

I retrieve the images from the folder and displayed in sliding manner

I have a doubt in my view page. Now I put in this way

**view**

```
 <div id="shopCarousel" class="carousel shopCarousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <!-- Indicators -->
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
          <li data-target="#shopCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
          <li data-target="#shopCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
          <li data-target="#shopCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>

        <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
          <div class="item active">
            <img src="<?echo base_url();?>application/assets/images/shops/1.jpg" alt="...">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
              ...
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <img src="<?echo base_url();?>application/assets/images/shops/2.jpg" alt="...">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
              ...
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="item">
            <img src="<?echo base_url();?>application/assets/images/shops/3.jpg" alt="...">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
              ...
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
```

Now I place each image directly. I want showing the images of that particular shop, now shows the same images in all shops.

I want this way, but images are not displayed.

Comment: I think using a for loop in view page for($i=0;$i<img_count;$i++) then add the code  <img src="<?echo base_url();?>application/assets/images/shops/$shop_id.'_'.$i.'.jpg'" alt="...">

Comment: But i dont know how this place in my view page

Answer (score 1):

Your required to use foreach loop for uploading the images, as it is replacing the last images in the for loop in the controller.

You should use it like

```
foreach($_FILES as $file)
{
    //your uploading code here using $file array
    //Store uploaded file names in a new array $files_uploaded
}
```

and also you can pass the array of the file list to the view by

```
$data['files'] = $files_uploaded;
$this->load->view('pages/',$data);
```

In the view

```
//Use the loop this way
<div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
<?php
foreach($files_uploaded AS $file){
?>
    <div class="item active">
        <img src="<?echo base_url();?>application/assets/images/shops/<?php echo  $file['name']; ?>" alt="...">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          ...
        </div>
    </div>
<?php
}
?>
</div>
```

Comment: if i upload 2 images then how i put the limit

Comment: using count() function, in PHP you can use if(count($_FILES)>2){ /**** show error ****/ }else{ /**** process upload ****/ } you can also use javascript to restrict the upload more than 2 files....

Comment: for($i=0;$i<img_count;$i++)
{
    <img src="<?echo base_url();?>application/assets/images/shops/$shop_id.'_'.$i.'.jpg'" alt="...">


 } this is my need..but its wrong

Comment: where the img_count comes from?

Comment: at the time of upload count the images..now that value i fetch from database

Comment: you should use count($_FILES) as it's more reliable

Comment: where i place this controller code in my controller? sry first time i'm try this

Comment: first put the foreach loop i gave in the answer foreach($_FILES AS $file) and then process upload using $file and not $_FILES

Comment: If you come to chat, I can show you how can this be done. Here giving lot of comments is time consuming....